# how to find whether taskbar is locked or not using win32 API

Tags: windows, winapi, native

I would like to query whether the taskbar is locked or not in the system using win32 API.

How can i do this ?

Comment: I don't think there's an API for that. You are not expected to want to know or care about that. It's entirely a user setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in registry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

`TaskbarSizeMove = 0` *Locked*

`TaskbarSizeMove = 1` *Unlocked*

You can access registry with win API : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: is there any other way to do this by calling single api function and without using registry operation ?